# how to convert integer to hex signed 2's complement:

Tags: java, type-conversion, hex, twos-complement

Pretty basic stuff i am sure but bits are not my forte.

So for some internal calculation i am trying to convert a given input ( constraint is that it would be a integer string for sure) into its hex equivalent, what stumped me is on how to get
Hex signed 2's complement:

My noob code:

```
   private String toHex(String arg, boolean isAllInt) {
        String hexVal = null;
        log.info("arg {}, isAllInt {}", arg, isAllInt);
        if (isAllInt) {
            int intVal = Integer.parseInt(arg);
            hexVal = Integer.toHexString(intVal);
            // some magic to convert this hexVal to its 2's compliment
        } else {
            hexVal = String.format("%040x", new BigInteger(1, arg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        }
        log.info("str {} hex {}", arg, hexVal);
        return hexVal;
    }
```

Input: 00001 
Output: 1
Expected Output: 0001

Input: 00216 
Output: D8
Expected Output: 00D8

00216

Input: 1192633166
Output: 4716234E
Expected Output: 4716234E

any predefined library is much welcome or any other useful pointers!

Comment: If you want a signed 2s complement value, you have to specify a word-size in bits. What are you expecting to use for this? The smallest multiple of 4 possible?

Comment: thank you for your response, yes, minimum of 4 is expected given my use case.

Comment: Do you want to pad nombers with leading zeroes up to 16 bits to 4 hex digits and numbers up to 32 bits to 8 hex digits ? e.g. 0xa12345 should be 0x000a123456  or 0xa123456?

Comment: @nos yes sir...if it helps, my input is always upper-bounded to 10 digits max, example: 1192633166 / 1602135736

Comment: What is `isAllInt`?

Comment: @RayToal, so there are cases in which i have alpha-numeric string, so to prevent `Integer.parseInt(arg)` throw an error, i take that as an input. examples given above come with `isAllInt=true` but input like `IamOnSo` will come with `isAllInt =false`. i know its an overkill but in development stage i was just trying out couple of stuffs!

Comment: Ok two more questions, with negative numbers in the range -65536 to -1 do you still want 4 hex digits? Also when you say your input is bounded to 10 digits, is your highest value 9999999999 or 2147483647?

Comment: @RayToal: sorry my bad, should have mentioned my constraints,  my input is always upper-bounded to 10 digits max and will always be positive. So negative numbers are not really a concern. Also, this 10 digits represents a 4 byte timestamp, so not sure what would be the max val but 9999999999 does seem unrealistic to be honest!

Comment: Got it, so nos has your answer below, cheers.

Comment: @RayToal: yes and that does solve the purpose but i have a follow up question in that answer, if you can help me with that!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to pad the hex digits up to either 4 digits or 8 digits, do:

```
int intVal = Integer.parseInt(arg);
if (intVal >= 0 && intVal <= 0xffff) {
     hexVal = String.format("%04x", intVal);
} else {
     hexVal = String.format("%08x", intVal);
}
```

See [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) on how the format strings work.

Comment: noob question, here we are just padding with relevant values but by definition, 2's compliment is hex of negative of original value...if thats the case, how is padding doing this negation? or is my understanding wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Answering the two's complement aspect.

### Two's Complement Representation

Two's complement is an agreement how to represent signed integral numbers in e.g. 16 bits (in olden times, different representations have been used by various processors, e.g. one's complement or sign-magnitude).

Positive numbers and zero are represented as expected:

- 0 is `0000 0000 0000 0000` or hex `0000`
- 1 is `0000 0000 0000 0001` or hex `0001`
- 2 is `0000 0000 0000 0010` or hex `0002`
- 3 is `0000 0000 0000 0011` or hex `0003`
- 4 is `0000 0000 0000 0100` or hex `0004`

Negative numbers are represented by adding `1 0000 0000 0000 0000` to them, giving:

- -1 is `1111 1111 1111 1111` or hex `ffff`
- -2 is `1111 1111 1111 1110` or hex `fffe`
- -3 is `1111 1111 1111 1101` or hex `fffd`

This is equivalent to: take the positive representation, flip all bits, and add 1.

For negative numbers, the highest bit is always 1. And that's how the machine distinguishes positive and negative numbers.

All processors in use today do their integer arithmetic based on two's complement representation, so there's typically no need to do special tricks. All the Java datatypes like `byte`, `short`, `int`, and `long` are defined to be signed numbers in two's complement representation.

In a comment you wrote

> 2's compliment is hex of negative of original value

That mixes up the concepts a bit. Two's complement is basically defined on bit patterns, and groups of 4 bits from these bit patterns can nicely be written as hex digits. Two's complement is about representing negative values as bit patterns, but from your question and comments I read that you don't expect negative values, so two's complement shouldn't concern you.

### Hex Strings

To represent signed values as hex strings, Java (and most other languages / environments) simply looks at the bit patterns, ignoring their positive / negative interpretation, meaning that e.g. -30 (`1111 1111 1110 0010`) does not get shown as "-1e" with a minus sign, but as "ffe2".

Because of this, negative values will always get translated to a string with maximum length according to the value's size (16 bits, 32 bits, 64 bits giving 4, 8, or 16 hex digits), because the highest bit will be 1, resulting in a leading hex digit surely not being zero. So for negative values, there's no need to do any padding.

Small positive values will have leading zeros in their hex representation, and Java's `toHexString()` method suppresses them, so 1 (0000 0000 0000 0001) becomes "1" and not "0001". That's why e.g. `format("%04x", ...)`, as in @nos's answer, is useful.